# MySQL TIMEDIFF after midnight

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('23:55:00','00:05:00')
```

Result:

```
23:50:00
```

I'd like the result to be

```
00:10:00
```

How do I make timediff look for the smallest difference between two time stamps?

Comment: You could try to find the shift that is closest to the punch time.

Comment: If you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)